# What is the meaning of this errors?

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I downloaded the driver for LCD touch display (KeDei 3.5 inch SPI TFTLCD version 3.0 20015/12/1) from http://kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz. Afterward I unpacked it

`tar -xzvf LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz` on `/home/pi/`

and I followed the instruction in that link: http://osoyoo.com/2016/09/13/install-raspberry-pi-3-5-touch-screen-driver-for-raspbian-jessie/.

I tried to do it twice, the first time with Raspbian Stretch Lite + update + upgrade and disconnected from Internet and that is the error that I found:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/LCD_show_v6_1_3 $ ./LCD35_v
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4:2: Extra junk at end of file
```

Note: I had to prepare my microSD cards again because the Raspbian not response when I did ping to it.

The second time  I tried with a fresh Raspbian Stretch Lite and that is the second error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/LCD_show_v6_1_3 $ ./LCD35_v
raspberrypi-kernel set on hold.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file and check if APT syntax is correct.

[Here is a post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342179/how-to-solve-extra-junk-at-end-of-file-when-using-apt) that may be helpful in your situation.